# (Dis)Advantages of being a "Hero of the Storm"?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

So I've had some good games lately and I achieved the "Hero of the Storm" killstreak.But are there any advantages or bad things when getting this streak aside from having a glowy health bar?

In LoL,when you have a high kill streak,killing you gives bonus gold to your oppenents,is there anything similar in HotS?Like giving bonus experience on death or even gaining more experience from minions and mercenaries?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [July, 25, 2014 Patch Notes](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/blog/14537490/heroes-technical-alpha-patch-notes-june-25-2014-6-25-2014), this was added:

**Kill Streaks**

> A kill streak meter has been added next to the in-game Hero portrait.
>
> Notifications are displayed at the top of the screen when a player achieves kill streaks of 5, 10, 15, and 20.
>
> Players’ nameplates now light up or catch fire to show off when they’ve achieved lengthy kill streaks.
>
> Kill streaks are reset upon death.

There is no mentioned of any sort of reward, except that they light up.

Comment: And with that lighting up, warns people of the dangers of that hero. Since there's no gold in HotS, exp would be the only thing. It doesn't matter what kill-streak a hero has since heroes as a whole are, I believe, worth the same (minus Murky).

Comment: Thank you.Not what I had hoped for though,but it's still alpha :)